# HTML How to Pad Content

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I'm trying to make a "Pad" but I'm completely lost as to how to do so.

If you go to the Fiddle you see "Content" is padded. This is on purpose, I know how to do this with a table.

However, with the javascript including portion I found that if I included a table everything is shown regardless of the script and div tags, which isn't what I want.

What I need is to find a way to pad the section that is after "Content" so it aligns. Maybe I'm constructing the table incorrectly, at this point I'm more curious as to how one would do so without using tables in HTML.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

**Javascript:**

```
function selection(){
    var myEvaluator = addendaList.options[addendaList.selectedIndex].value;
    var referenceNumberId = document.getElementById("referenceNumberBlock");
    var deliveryIdentificationId = document.getElementById("deliveryIdentificationBlock");
    var currencyISOCodeId = document.getElementById("currencyISOCodeBlock");
    var referenceTrafficId = document.getElementById("referenceTrafficBlock");

    if( myEvaluator == "IMP" ) {
        referenceNumberId.style.display         = "block";
        deliveryIdentificationId.style.display  = "block";
        currencyISOCodeId.style.display         = "none";
        referenceTrafficId.style.display        = "none";
    } else if ( myEvaluator == "EXP" ) {
        referenceNumberId.style.display         = "none";
        deliveryIdentificationId.style.display  = "none";
        currencyISOCodeId.style.display         = "block";
        referenceTrafficId.style.display        = "block";
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<table width="620" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <td width="160" valign="top">
        <b>Content</b>
    </td>
</table>

    <b>Select an option:  </b>
    <select name = "code" id = "addendaList" onChange = "select()">
        <option value = "IMP">Import</option>
        <option value = "EXP">Export</option>
    </select>

    <div ID = "referenceNumberBlock" style = "display:block;">
        <b>Reference Number: </b>
            <input name = "referenceNumber" id = "referenceNumber" type = "text" size = "16" maxlength="15" value = "">
    </div>

    <div ID = "deliveryIdentificationBlock" style = "display:block;">
        <b>Delivery Identification: </b>
            <input id = "deliveryIdentification" name = "deliveryIDentification" type = "text" size = "16" maxlength = "30" value = "">
    </div>

    <div ID = "currencyISOCodeBlock" style = "display:none;">
        <b>Currency ISO Code: </b>
             <select id = "ISOCodes" name = "currencyISOCode">
                 <option value = "MXN">MXN</option>
                 <option value = "USD">USD</option>
             </select>
    </div>

    <div ID = "referenceTrafficBlock" style ="display:none;">
        <b>Traffic Number: </b>
            <input name = "referenceTraffic" type = "text" size = "16" maxlength = "20" value = "">
    <div>
</body>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tL98L/4/

**Updated Fiddle with it solved:** http://jsfiddle.net/tL98L/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround everything you want to pad with a `<div class="wrapper">` and add this to your css:

```
.wrapper { padding-left: 15px }
```

That should work

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer, however, how would one know how much the padding needs to be?

You know what they say, give a man a fish.

Comment: Also. What fixed it was

.wrapper { padding-left: 100px }

Not 15. But the idea is correct

Comment: 1) Use % on your css, so that it'll behave based on screen size
2) Use javascript. By using "window.screen.availWidth" you get the available available window size. Then, you can make some calculations to resize the padding accordingly.

I recommend using only css, though

Comment: great advice! Sadly I'm editing some legacy code and doing that would require an immense amount of code editing, which I hope I don't have to do, so this quick 'n dirty fix is just perfect.

Answer (score 1):

hi Erick can u please try the below code if any thing else you need then please let me know.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #mydata tr td
    {
        padding-left:5px;
    }
    #mydata tr td:first-child
    {
        text-align:right;
    }
    #mydata input[type="text"]
    {
        width:170px;
        height:27px;        
    }
    select
    {
        width:179px;
        height:33px;
    }
    #mydata input[type="text"] , select
    {
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    </style>


<div>
<table id="mydata">
<tr>
<td>Select an Option:</td>
<td>
<select name = "code" id = "addendaList" onChange = "select()">
        <option value = "IMP">Import</option>
        <option value = "EXP">Export</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Reference Number:</td>
<td><input name = "referenceNumber" id = "referenceNumber" type = "text" size = "16" maxlength="15" value = ""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Delivery Identification:</td>
<td><input id = "deliveryIdentification" name = "deliveryIDentification" type = "text" size = "16" maxlength = "30" value = ""></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Prafulla.

This implementation sadly breaks a number of things, mostly since we are sending a "style" it breaks the JS, which I'm sure has a work-around but I sadly don't have the luxury of finding it at the moment.

Comment: Let me add and note that this looks 1000 times better than what I have, and if I had the time I would definitely rewrite everything this way.